# Existence and uniqueness of particular binary operations on a lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $(A, \le)$ be a lattice. Consider the following properties for a commutative operation $\cdot$ on $A$:
$$c \cdot (a \wedge b) = (c \cdot a) \wedge (c \cdot b)$$
$$c \cdot (a \vee b) = (c \cdot a) \vee (c \cdot b)$$
$$a \cdot b = (a \wedge b) \cdot (a \vee b)$$
for all $a,b,c \in A$. (Actually, the third property comes from the first two, as pointed out by Xodarap in his answer below.)

For example, both $\wedge$ and $\vee$ satisfy the properties if and only if the lattice is distributive. Furthermore, if the lattice has a greatest (resp. least) element, then it is an identity for $\wedge$ (resp. $\vee$).

My question is the following:

> What are some natural conditions on the lattice that guarantee the existence of an operation satisfying the properties above other than $\wedge$ and $\vee$? What other assumptions can we make (possibly on $\cdot$) to guarantee uniqueness?

I am mostly interested in **associative operations with an identity**.

The question arose from the problem of writing the sum and product of natural numbers in terms of the lattice operations respectively of $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, \mid)$. In those cases I already know the existence of such operations, which are hidden in the definitions of the orders. Indeed, both orders are of the form $a \preceq b$ if and only if there exists $c$ such that $b = a*c$.

Actually, the construction of an order $\preceq$ like that can be carried out in any commutative monoid where the identity is irreducible and the cancellation law holds, but $\preceq$ is not necessarily a lattice order, unless $*$ enjoys a unique factorization property. Furthermore, uniqueness does not seem to follow from these premises only.

Comment: Consider the operation that takes any two points to a single fixed point 0. This would satisfy all the equalities above, right? Maybe you want the operation to also have an inverse?

Comment: Yes, it would. It wouldn't have an identity though, and your example has just convinced me that this should be a requirement. I am not sure about inverses, because neither the sum nor the product of natural numbers have inverse operations.

Comment: Ah, good point. Maybe you should edit the question so people see it as a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two hold true in any lattice-ordered group, and the third one is a consequence of the first two in any l-monoid:

Note that $(a\vee b)(a\wedge b)$ is equal to $(a^2\vee ab)\wedge(ab\vee b^2)$ - clearly $ab\leq (a^2\vee ab),(ab\vee b^2)$ so $ab$ is a lower bound of this product. An analogous one shows that $ab\geq (a\vee b)(a\wedge b)$ and therefore we conclude that $ab=(a\vee b)(a\wedge b)$.

Your last question is about uniqueness - I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but given that you can order monoids in a lot of different ways, I think you will need to put restrictions on both the ordering and the operation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that the third property was a consequence of the first two. But I still can't see why the first two would hold in all lattice-ordered commutative monoids: it's clear that $c(a\wedge b) \le ca \wedge cb$, but from $d \le ca,\, cb$ how do you deduce that $d \le c(a\wedge b)$?

Comment: You're right, I think you need inverses for this to work. I updated the answer.